# Arduino excecutabe not found

Tags: macos, arduino, visual-studio-code

I´ve some problems to set up the Arduino extension (0.2.15). I get always
"[Error] Exit with code=undefined" and the extension says "Cannot find Arduino executable program under directory /Applications".

I use Arduino Version 1.8.5 which was originally installed in the Downloads-Folder. I moved it to Applications.

The Arduino-IDE works fine
my settings file:

```
"arduino.path": "/Applications",
"arduino.commandPath": "Contents/MacOS/Arduino",
"arduino.additionalUrls": "",
"arduino.logLevel": "info",
"arduino.enableUSBDetection": false,

"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
```

and my Arduino.json

```
"board": "espressif:esp32:esp32",
"configuration": "PartitionScheme=default,FlashMode=qio,FlashFreq=80,FlashSize=4M,UploadSpeed=921600,DebugLevel=none",
"port": "/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART",
"sketch": "Blink.ino"
```

Ive no idea what's going wrong

Michael,..,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can be wrong because I'm not on a MacOS, but try it:

```
"arduino.path": "/Applications/arduino-1.8.5",
"arduino.commandPath": "Contents/MacOS/run-arduino.sh"
```